# MITM attack in a star network with proxy server

Tags: man-in-the-middle, proxy

My community centre has a public computer center. I am pretty sure that it's connected in a star topology with some switch in the center. It also have a proxy server which we need to enter a username and password to access the internet. The username and password can be requested from the service counter near the public computer center.

My question is that how might somebody using the community centre's computer do a MiTM attack on me also using the community centre's computer. Secondly, how might I be able to protect myself from such attacks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Security on a computer not controlled by you is relatively hard, but here's the best advice I can give:

Use strong authenticated encryption.  Whenever the question is "how do I protect against MITM attacks", the answer is always "use strong authenticated encryption."  For web browsing, this means TLS (HTTPS) without mixed content and with valid certificates.

Given that this is a community center computer, I'm not going to suggest techniques like using a VPN, TOR, or other proxies, since you're probably not in a position to be installing software.

Also, on a shared/public computer, you want to watch out for malware as much as possible.  Hopefully they use up-to-date anti-malware software.  (Again, on a computer not controlled by you, you don't have much ability to change this, but can at least be aware of the risk.)